# Get device driver properties in Windows using Python

Tags: python, windows, driver

I would need to create a Python script that monitors the state of a Windows device driver.
Specifically I'm interested on getting these infos: "is connected", "is present", "needs restart", "has problem". [reference photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVVtK.png). The monitored device is a touch screen.

I have tried searching for solution for win32api in Python but cannot find a solution to get these specific details. Also I tried searcing the registeries but I cant find if the wanted details are saved and readable somewhere in there. Any assistance is appreciated

Comment: Getting exactly those parameters can be tricky. What exactly are you trying to monitor? For example only monitoring the status and error code of the device can be much much simpler.

Comment: @ODgn The use case of such touch screen is for SCADA HMI of a safety related system. I would like to be able to monitor the state of the touch screen and indicate any faults or disconnects to a PLC. I was thinking about using Python for this since it has library for Modbus TCP which I could use to transmit the state of the touch screen.